# Is $x=i²$ the solution of this equation $2018^x+2018x+2018=0 $ in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: proof-verification, lambert-w

[Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2018%5Ex%2B2018x%2B2018%3D0) showed that the solution of that  equation $2018^x+2018x+2018=0 $  closed to $x=-1$ , Then can I consider that $x=i^2$ is the solution of the titled equation in $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: Is "closed to -1" supposed to be "close to -1"?

Comment: $i^2$ is real, and *is* $-1$. So. yeah, you can say that solution is **close to** $i^2$

Comment: BTW, why is this question tagged under Lambert-W?

Comment: This just says that $\frac{1}{2018}$ is close to 0.

Comment: No, because if you put that exact value into the equation, it isn't a solution.

Comment: @JaideepKhare: The closed form soultion does indeed use the Lambert-W function: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2018%5Ex%2B2018x%2B2018%3D0

Comment: What are you trying to do.  Are you trying to find **all** complex solutions?

Comment: The exact solution is more like $x = -1.0000002455595702422632167564883213844621715209521\dots$.

Comment: it is easier to write it as $$-1-e^{(x-1)\ln 2018}=x$$ and approach the solution by recursion.

Comment: In addition, why exactly do we need to write $-1 = i^2$?